# How would the world be different if we orbited a different star to our Sun?

Tags: science-based, hard-science, stars

I was reading [this article on stars that are just right for the formation of habitable planets](https://earthsky.org/space/k-stars-goldilocks-stars-ideal-for-habitable-planets), and I was interested in what it had to say about K stars.  Here is an except so you can read for yourself:

> Surprisingly, according to Arney’s study, the best stars might not be those like our sun. Instead, K stars – dimmer then our sun but brighter than M-type red dwarfs – might be the ideal candidates. K stars can live for 17 to 70 billion years, much longer than sunlike stars, which shine on the main sequence for only about 10 billion years. The longer lifespan of a K star would give life on an orbiting planet more time to evolve, if it ever got started.
>
> K stars are also less active in their youth, with fewer extreme solar flares that could wipe out any life on a young planet. By contrast, small M-type red dwarfs are more intensely active; life starting out on a planet orbiting an M star would need to find a way to survive, somehow, in an extreme environment.

My question is, what differences would we notice in the world around us if we lived on an Earth-like planet orbiting a K star?  Specifically differences caused by the change of star (and the adjusted distance from it to keep the planet in the goldilocks zone).

Would the differences be in the sky alone (i.e. just cosmetic differences), or would they be more fundamental than that?

Comment: This question is extremely broad.  There would be vast climatological, geographical, and geological differences, as well as, if life were even to evolve, massive biological differences.  Please narrow your question to one specific area, so as to make valid answers shorter than a book.

Comment: @Gryphon One of my intentions of this question was to determine if changing the Sun would make huge changes or just cosmetic one (as stated in the last line of my question) - to put it in other words, the question is asking if the ramifications would be specific or broad - obviously you think the answer to this is "broad"...  However the one and only answer to this question almost states the opposite - which I find confusing

Comment: @Gryphon consider this scenario: 1 person asks "would changing X produce cosmetic differences or broad differences" - 2 people answer - 1 answer being "it wouldn't be too broad" and the other answer being "this is too broad, I am shutting your question down, no further discussion allowed on this question"

Comment: I count two questions in your question (which is also a sign that points toward too broad).  One does indeed ask whether the changes would be broad or cosmetic.  The other asks, and I quote, "what differences would we notice in the world around us if we lived on an Earth-like planet orbiting a K star?"  This is far too broad.  If you wish to, you can [edit] the question to narrow it down and make it a better fit for this site (by, for example, making it clear that the actual question is the second one in the question).

Answer (score 3):

The changes don't *need* to be drastic.

I'm going to be using the appropriate figures (mass, radius, luminosity, etc) for the K2V star [Epsilon Eridani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon_Eridani), because I felt like it. I'm not going to go into detail on any of the changes I've found, because there are too many and they are too complex and I am not [omnidisciplinary scientist](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/OmnidisciplinaryScientist). Sorry.

So first, the changes to the numbers:

Using the [radiative equilibrium temperature](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/10116/30460) equation, you can see that the required radius for a circular orbit giving a copy of Earth the same equilibrium temperature is about 0.6AU. I tried throwing Epsilon Eridani's figures into the habitable zone calculator on [this webpage](http://astro.df.unipi.it/stellar-models/HZ/index.php), which gives an inner 4Gyr habitable radius of about 0.61AU. Given the different sets of assumptions being used, this seems close enough. That'll give a [year length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_period) about half that of earth.

Epsilon Eridani has .735 the radius of the Sun, but at .6 the orbital radius it'll have an angular diameter that's about 23% larger than the Sun's apparent size from Earth. Assuming the same size moon as Earth, you'll get no total eclipses, only annular ones.

Now, [tidal locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking) is a tricky thing to estimate, but given identical copies of Earth, one around the Sun at 1AU and one around our K2V star at 0.6AU, we can at least get a rough handle on how much more quickly one is likely to become tidally locked than the other. The simplified approximation on the wikipedia page suggests that locking times for circular orbits are proportional to the sixth power of the orbital radius, and inversely proportional to stellar mass. The Earth around the Epsilon Eridani-like star will therefore become tidally locked about 18 times faster than Earth, but is unlikely to become locked during the time the parent star is on the main sequence so that doesn't seem to be an issue either.

---

Now, a few of the effects.

Winters will be much more brief, which will have some non-trivial knock-on effects on how things like hibernation or deciduous plants arise. It'll also moderate the highs and lows of sea temperatures, which might have very major effects on [thermohaline circulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermohaline_circulation). In turn, this may have drastic effects on things like the fertility of oceans, and remember that phytoplankton produce [50-85%](https://earthsky.org/earth/how-much-do-oceans-add-to-worlds-oxygen) of our oxygen on Earth. Lack of ocean fertility means formation of things like [limestone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limestone), [chalk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chalk) and possibly [flint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flint), all of which are formed from the bodies of marine life, *may* be reduced (which is problematic for any stoneage-equivalent people). Shallower water coastal biomes would still exist, so this change doesn't preclude the existence of marine life (and hence the existence of minerals derived from it), though artic and antarctic plankton-based food webs could be much smaller or even absent entirely. Anaerobes in the larger areas of [anoxic sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anoxic_waters) could still exist, but with a much reduced volume of nutrients floating down from surface marine biomes the production of oil seems likely to be reduced (no, it isn't made from dead dinosaurs, sorry). Coal formation still seems like it could occur in the same way as it did on Earth, assuming trees could evolve in the first place.

It is *possible* that ocean circulation might have been critical for the evolution of complex life in the sea that could then migrate to the land. I can't actually back up this particular hunch with any references, but consider that vast euxinic oceans might not lead to exciting terrestrial biomes. It is all pure supposition though, and there's plenty of scope for handwaving to get something closer to what you'd like.

Comment: Excellent answer. Like your approach in using a specific K dwarf star as an example for the circumstances of a planet orbiting a K star. An answer to a question like this will always general ones. Plus one for well done.